# Start namenode without formatting

Tags: hadoop, format, startup, hadoop2

I tried to start namenode using bin/start-all.sh. But, this command doesnt start namenode.  I know if I do bin/hadoop namenode -format , namenode will start but in that case, I will lose all my data. Is there a way to start namenode without formatting it?

Answer (score 4):

Your problem might be related to the following:

Hadoop writes its NameNode data in /tmp/hadoop- folder by default which is cleaned after every reboot.

Add following property to  conf/hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
   <value><path to your desired folder></value>
</property>
```

The "dfs.name.dir" property allows you to control where Hadoop writes NameNode metadata.

Comment: Upvoted this, it solved the problem for me. (now hdfs-site is located in etc/hadoop in 2.x)

Answer (score 1):

`bin/start-all.sh` should start the namenode, as well as the datanodes, the jobtracker and the tasktrackers. So, check the log of the namenode for possible errors.

An alternative way to skip starting the jobtracker and the tasktrackers and just start the namenode (and the datanodes) is by using the command:
`bin/start-dfs.sh`

Actually, `bin/start-all.sh` is equivalent to using the commands:

`bin/start-dfs.sh`, which starts the namenode and datanodes and 
`bin/start-mapred.sh`, which starts the jobtracker and the tasktrackers.

For more details, visit [this page](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/GettingStartedWithHadoop).

Comment: You have just reiterated what I posted.

Comment: What do you mean? From what I understood from your question, the namenode is not starting unless you format it. Did you check the logs of the namenode? Normally, namenode starts without the need to format it each time...

Comment: Yes, I did check the logs . There was a problem with the dfs.data.dir and dfs.name.dir.

Comment: Please, edit your question and post these error messages. Usually, these are related to user privileges (write access for the hadoop user), or even a typo in `hdfs-site.xml`, but this is just guessing without seeing the error messages.